# Facebook social plugin using Graph API v2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm terribly stacked into this silly situation where i cannot make the standard Facebook Like Button plugin to work.
I'm using the default code that Facebook suggests with no luck:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=189637597750754&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and have the classic elements as well:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/07sj57cx/)

I  really cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: I've added these components to a test page and they are working fine... Have you a sample url where you have added the code?

Comment: Does the fiddle demo works for you?

Comment: No the fiddle demo didn't work. That was why I tried it on a separate webpage.

Comment: Were you able to get this working when using a normal page?

Comment: For some reason, the same code started working a couple of days later. Maybe it had something to do with FB api. Thanks for your help!